# Connecting an ethernet only device to a WiFi only network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I've run into a bit of a predicatment, I have an ethernet only device, an Epson thermal printer for a POS system, that needs to be connected to a wireless only network.

The reason it can only be wireless is due to the lease of the store saying cable can't be run through the walls, holes can't be cut, etc. And to even get to the counter you'd need to run the cable through the floor or across it, leaving a lovely mess of cables on the floor.

I'm wondering if there is any solution to this problem, other than buying an expensive wireless enabled printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a wireless Ethernet bridge.   Something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003KPBRRW).  You should be able to find them cheaper if you look around.  These bridges turn a wired Ethernet device into a wireless device.